# Node js throws MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended while updating multiple documents in multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to update multiple documents in multiple collections in a DB. While doing that Mongo throws an error after the first collection. And doesn't make changes on the after ones.

Error

> Assertion failed: MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended

```
const migration = async function migrate(client, dbName) {
    const engineDatabase = client.db(dbName);
    console.log(`connected to db ${engineDatabase.databaseName}`);

    const collections = await engineDatabase.collections();
    for (const collection of collections) {
        console.log(collection.collectionName);
        collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"ownerIds": ["-1", "1"]}}, function (err, res) {
            console.assert(err == null, err);

            console.log(res.result.nModified + " document(s) updated");
            }
        ) 
    }
};
module.exports = migration;
```

Do I have to close the client after every update? Or do I have to wait for the next update? I couldn't get what's the point of this error.

Answer (score 1):

This part is asynchronous

```
collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"ownerIds": ["-1", "1"]}}, function (err, res) {
  console.assert(err == null, err);

  console.log(res.result.nModified + " document(s) updated");
})
```

Whats happening is your program is finishing while the `updateMany` is not yet done.

And you're already using `async/await`, you don't need to have a callback there.

You can instead do

```
const res = await collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {"ownerIds": ["-1", "1"]}});
console.log(res.result.nModified + " document(s) updated");
```