# Why am I still getting MongoExpiredSessionError even though I'm parsing the json in my azure function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, debugging, azure-functions

With regards to my Azure function, I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting `MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended` error when trying to do an extremely simple insertion.  I've tried `JSON.parse(result);` and `JSON.stringify(result);` but still getting the same error.

I've also tried removing the `finally` block, tried adding `await` in front of `collection()` but still getting the same error.  I've pretty much done all the I can that I've found on the web to troubleshoot but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "myUri"

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser:true}).catch(err => {context.log(err); });

    let result = null;
    let callerEntityProfile = req.body.CallerEntityProfile;
    let packIdInput = callerEntityProfile.Entity.PackIdInput;
    let userId = callerEntityProfile.Entity.UserID;

    try {
        const db = await client.db("myDB");
        let collection = await db.collection("myCollection");
        let query = { userId : userId };
        result = await collection.findOne(query);

        let insertPack = {
          "PackId" : packIdInput
        };

        result.packsOwned.push(insertPack);

        JSON.parse(result);

        collection.insertOne(result, function(err, r) {
          console.log('inside insertOne')
          console.log(err); // this is where it's showing the error message
        });

    }
    catch (err) {
        context.log(err);
    }
    finally {
        client.close();
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not wait until the end of the asynchronous function, the close action is faster than insertMany action. You can try the following:

```js
const DB = client.db(databasename);

const myAsyncFunction = async() => {
  const collection = await DB.collection(nameofcollection); // do this INSIDE async function

  await collection.insertMany(details); // similarly inside async
};

client.close();
```

Alternatively, you may try something like this:

```js
client.connect(err => {
  if(err) return console.log(err);

  client.db(databasename).collection(nameofcollection)
      .then(collection => collection.insertMany(details))
      .then(() => client.close());
});
```

You can refer to these similar SO threads -
[How to fix MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816298/how-to-fix-mongoerror-cannot-use-a-session-that-has-ended)
[MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270529/mongoerror-cannot-use-a-session-that-has-ended)
[Node js throws MongoError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818654/node-js-throws-mongoerror-cannot-use-a-session-that-has-ended-while-updating-mu)
[MongoError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849766/mongoerror-cannot-use-a-session-that-has-ended-only-on-1-collection)